# How do I create this "fade in message box"

Tags: html, css, message, box

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e7PB.png)

When I hover my mouse on the box, this message box fade in on top. How do I make something like that? Can I make it with CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the code with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

find this easy way to make tooltip : [here](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/)

and here also another plugin to do this : [here](http://protip.rocks/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me how to add images and a <br>'s in the toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it with CSS transition.

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fade:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/x4dd500z/1/

Answer (score 0):

First set the properties for msgbox then

For fading use this

```
msgbox {
  opacity: 1;
}

 msgbox:hover {
   opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: - **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgh5qqLj/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    <span>Tooltip</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:2px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:10px;
}


span {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:2px 0;
    background-color:#000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);

    color:#fff;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
}


.box:hover span {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I want the tooltip outside the box and when I hover over the box - tooltip shows. And I don't want the tooltip shows when I hover over it. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: YES! Thank you a lot! :*